# Odoo 12 Installation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, odoo

I have tried to install Odoo 12 in Ubuntu 18.04 (VM) and found the below error.

While trying to run the command " sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list " in the terminal I got the below error.

```
sudo: vim: command not found
```

Can any one please help me to install Odoo 12 on my VM?

Comment: If it enlightens you, the error means that `vim` isn't found or hasn't been installed on your terminal (not sure if Ubuntu prepackages vim). This might redirect you to Googling for some more. (N.B. I've added the Python tag since it's in the description of odoo.) You're more likely to find far better answers and suggestions at https://superuser.com.

Comment: I suspect this has been voted down because if you don't understand this trivial error, then you are unlikely to succeed in this task. You would also be further ahead using the editor nano, which is already installed in Ubuntu, and does not require you to learn obscure editor commands (regardless of how powerful vi/vim enthusiasts think they are). For which the command would be:
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

Answer (score 2):

Might be `vim` editor is not there in your system. You can install is via following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```